# In Magento 2, where to add custom javascript files and resources?

Tags: javascript, magento2

In Magento 2, where to specify JavaScript resources? If it's an update to a layout, is it good to edit the JavaScript resources that belong to other modules and themes?

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript Resources can be specified at several levels:

- At the library level for all libraries in the Magento code base:

  lib/web
- At the module level for all libraries within a module:

  app/code/{Namespace}/{Module}/view/{area}/web
- At the theme module level for all libraries within a theme:

  app/design/{area}/{Vdndor}/{theme}/{Namespace}/{Module}/web
- At the theme level for all libraries within a theme:

  app/design/{area}/{Vendor}/{theme}/web

It is recommended to specify JavaScript resources in templates rather than in layout updates, to ensure that resources are processed in the body of a page.

To ensure that themes and modules work as designed, do not edit the JavaScript resources that belong to other modules and themes.